# Load factor of Arraylist and Vector?

Tags: java, collections

Hi I was trying to find the load factor of Array list and vector but I was not able to find it. I know load factor of HashMap and other Map is 0.75. Can any one help to find me how to check the load factor of Vector and Arraylist.

Comment: Vector and ArrayList don't have a load factor.

Comment: Here's a related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540583/why-does-map-has-loadfactor-and-list-does-not-have-it/

Comment: @Eran thanks for the valuable link and your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you would like to know how `ArrayList` and `Vector` increase its size.

For `ArrayList`, every time you put an element into it, it will check if the nested array needs to be enlarge its size. If yes, generally, its size will grow with:

```
newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
```

For some special case, for example, add many or huge number of elements, things will be different. Please refer `grow(int minCapacity)` function in `java.util.ArrayList` source code.

Regarding `Vector`, generally, its size will grow with:

```
newCapacity = oldCapacity + ((capacityIncrement > 0) ?
                                         capacityIncrement : oldCapacity);
```

For some special cases, please refer `grow(int minCapacity)` in `java.util.Vector`.

Comment: I have gone through the source code of Array and Vector as well. But are you sure what value oldCapacity and capacityIncrement holds.

Comment: @Som well, it depends on the initial value and how many element is adding to the nested array. There's a separate constructor for `ArrayList` and `Vector` to specify the initialCapacity and  capacityIncrement(only for `Vector`). If you use the non-parameterized constructor, then the value will be initialized with **default value**.

Answer (score 11):

**ArrayList:**

- Initial Capacity:10
- Load Factor:1 (when the list is full)
- Growth Rate: current_size + current_size/2

**Vector:**

- Initial Capacity:10
- Load Factor:1 (when the list is full)
- Growth Rate: 
  current_size * 2 (if capacityIncrement is not defined)
  current_size + capacityIncrement (if capacityIncrement is defined during vector initialization)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16160306)

Comment: Removed the link and only kept explanation in above comment.

Answer (score -1):

> ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
>   for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
>   al.add(i+1);
>   }
>   default capacity = 10
>   in the above example, we want to add 11 elements so new Capacity of ArrayList is
>   int newCapacity = (oldcapacity*3)/2+1
>    (10*3)/2+1 = 16